# Parsing Json data with imageview using Volley and Picasso and displaying in Recycler and Card View

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley, picasso

My data shows in logcat but displays nothing while opening app. You can further view over [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKxKt.jpg) But I found a problem "No adapter attached : skipping layout" Any idea with this problem?

This is my **MainActivity xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**CardView xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 android:id="@+id/card_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:elevation="3dp"
 card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
 card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
 card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imagebtn"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="100dp"
         android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imagebtn"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:textColor="#000"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Hospital Name"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity java class file:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
 public  static final String EXTRA_CREATOR = "orga_organame";
 public  static final String EXTRA_URL = 
 "http://xelwel.com.np/hamrosewaapp/uploads/images/logo/civil.png";

 private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
 private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
 private List<UserInfo> mExampleList;
 private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

ImageButton imageButton;
TextView textView;
ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imagebtn);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.description);

    mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    jsonParse();
  }

 public void jsonParse() {

    final String url = 
  ("http://xelwel.com.np/hamrosewaapp/api/get_organization_list");

    final StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
   url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.i("response", url + "response:" + response);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("org_list");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String hsname = obj.getString("orga_organame");
                    String image = obj.getString("logo_path" + "civil.png");

                    mExampleList.add(new UserInfo(hsname, image)); 
                }

                mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
              mExampleList);
                mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
                mExampleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Parsing Data", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went 
     wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();         
        }
     }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("api_key", "123456789");
            return params;
        }
    };

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
  }

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(int position) {

    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
    UserInfo clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, clickedItem.getImage_link());
    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR, clickedItem.getName());

    startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
  }
```

**DetailActivity java class file:**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    String imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
    String name = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view_detail);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().into(imageView);
    textView.setText(name);
```

**ExampleAdapter java class file:**

```
  public class ExampleAdapter extends 
  RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

  private Context mcontext;
  private List<UserInfo> mExampleList;
  private OnItemClickListener mListener;

  public interface OnItemClickListener{
     void onItemClick(int position);
  }

  public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
     mListener = listener;
  }

  public ExampleAdapter(Context context, List<UserInfo> list) {

    mcontext = context;
    mExampleList = list;
  }

 @Override
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = 
   LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.cardview,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    UserInfo info = mExampleList.get(position);

    String imageUrl = info.getImage_link();
    String hsname = info.getName();

    holder.textView.setText(hsname);

  Picasso.with(mcontext).load(imageUrl).fit().centerInside().
  into(holder.imageView);

  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
  }

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mListener!= null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position!= RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        mListener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
             }
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

**UserInfo java class file:**

```
    public class UserInfo {

    public String id, name, image_link;

    public UserInfo(String id, String name) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
   }

   public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return image_link;
  }

  public void setName(String image_link) {
    this.image_link = image_link;
 }

   public String getImage_link() {
    return image_link;
   }

 public void setImage_link(String image_link) {
    this.image_link = image_link;
    }
 }
```

These are my total code related with these problem. Please view the codes and response with some specific solution...

Comment: please add your json response here.

Comment: can you debugge your code?

Comment: @Ayush Katuwal please check my ans.

Comment: @Guruji I have edited my code, you can watch my json response...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

You made mistake in `UserInfo` class Constructor.

You added

```
 mExampleList.add(new UserInfo(hsname, image));
```

But here set id and name

```
 public UserInfo(String id, String name) {

   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
   }
```

**change your Constructor**

```
  public UserInfo(String name, String image_link) {

   this.image_link = image_link;
   this.name = name;
   }
```

You didn't set any value in `image_link` variable,But accessing in adapter class

```
UserInfo info = mExampleList.get(position);
String imageUrl = info.getImage_link();
String hsname = info.getName();
```

Comment: @Ayush Katuwal try this

Comment: Sir, I am new in android programming so I got confused with these issues, I've made some changes from your answer but it is still the same. Would you please guide me to have the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        String logoURL = jsonObject.getString("logo_path")

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("org_list");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

           JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

           String hsname = obj.getString("orga_organame");
           String imageurl = obj.getString("orga_image");
           String image = logoURL +"/"+ imageurl ;

           mExampleList.add(new UserInfo(hsname, image)); 
        }
}
```

Comment: @Ayush Katuwal i am checking your response and try my ans.

Comment: I do some changes from your answer but now I am having error in Adapter class as I am new in programming and due lack of ideas I am facing such problems would you help me to have my desired output. You can further download my project from github.com/ayushmng/RecyclerView and check there, the issues hiding in my project. I will be waiting for your response and sorry for late response...